# Can You Please Explain Module Description Based On This Diagrams?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, module, project

I'm doing my final year project. I have no idea about my project modules. But The Company Gives these diagrams to implement the project so anyone please tell about the module description based on these diagrams.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you managed to determine yourself so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When my husband was in his last year of engineering, the problem he had to solve included purposely incorrect data from the "company".